# How to fit and keep video below transparent background?

Tags: html, css, video

I have .PNG background image with transparent oval shape and I want to put video under the oval shape. I used z-index to put it under, but I don't know how to keep video at same size as transparent part without overflowing or video being to small when doing resposive design.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="section9 sm:pt-8 lg:grid lg:grid-rows-1 lg:grid-cols-2">
            <video class="video" width="920" height="840" loop="true" autoplay="autoplay" controls="false" id="vid" muted>
                <source src="../img/short-video-to-put-to-case-study-html.mp4" class="videopl" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        <div class="section9-content space-y-2 lg:space-y-6 sm:text-center sm:top-3/4 lg:row-span-1 lg:col-start-2 lg:col-end-3 lg:place-self-center">
            <h1 class="font-black text-2xl lg:text-6xl wow animate__animated animate__bounce"><span class="lg:block"></span></h1>
            <p class="text-sm section9-text"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is CSS code:

```
    .section9 {
    background: url("../img/section9.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
    position: relative;
    height: 800px;
}

.video {
    left: -80px;
    top: 130px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    cursor: default;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    display: none !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

.section9-content {
    font-family: 'GalanoGrotesque-Regular';
    color: var(--grassGreen);
}

.section9-text {
    color: var(--gray);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting both image and video components inside a wrapper(parent div), making their positions absolute with width and height 100%, with z-index of the video being lower than the image.

```html
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Then you can resize the wrapper component and they should be resized together with it.

If you want your video to be in `cover` mode, you can give it the `object-fit: cover;` property